# Is it possible to create arbitrary shapes of magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I've been reading about Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation (TMS) which can activate neurons using a magnetic field, which got me thinking... what if we can pick and choose exactly which neurons to activate? Then we'd be able to create true non-invasive in-brain virtual reality.

For that to be possible, we'd need to be able to make a magnetic field of any shape, probably by combining the magnetic fields of hundreds of different electromagnets and having them "sum" to the final desired vector field...

Also, we would have to be able to pick and choose the "dead zones" so we don't stimulate every single neuron within range. Are there even dead zones in magnetic fields? Is this possible?

Comment: Nope. Maxwell's equations limit us greatly in the kinds of fields we can make.

Comment: Trivially no: the field must be always divergence-less until someone finds a monopole (or several).

Comment: Which shape would you create? And I might be of some help

Comment: In some way it is possible, see [Halbach array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array).

Answer (score -2):

yes. the usage of steering static magnets on a larger or smaller field are employed in the old crt's and accelerators. these are some times referred to as focusing magnets. both static and electric magnets.

Comment: Any comment on the "dead zones" aspect?

Comment: Maybe dead zones aren't necessary if you can focus them enough. But they'd have to be focusable on a point of space which seems hard